# Aurelia - switching to another app by "setRoot" and handling promise rejection

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm building app that has separate public and private parts(in other words it's combined from 2 internal apps - in context of aurelia.setRoot...):

- public part its mainly login mechanic
- private part is aviable after sucessfully login

Application flow looks like:

1. navigate to url, eg: `http://app/user/details/2` (which means that wants to see details page for user which id = 2)
2. Apps check if user is logged in - if it is then go to step 4, otherwise go to 3.
3. User is redirecter to public part of application - login page - but ulr is not changed
4. when user is logged, i'm calling `aurelia.setRoot(PRIVATE)` and processing request - page with user details is beein loaded

Between 'setRoot' calls, I'm clearing appRouter by calling:

`appRouter.reset();
appRouter.deactivate();`

navigation history is not cleared - which allows to process ulr after sucessfuly logging in

everything works fine(happy flow) until requested page from any reason will return rejected promise from VM `activate` method

From my obserwations:

- appRouter.history.previousLocation is set to `http://app/user/details/2`- which is not clear for my - previous location should be empty/null/undefined
- appRouter.restorePreviousLocation is called - from source code

  `function restorePreviousLocation(router) {
    let previousLocation = router.history.previousLocation;
    if (previousLocation) {
      router.navigate(router.history.previousLocation, { trigger: false, replace: true });
    } else if (router.fallbackRoute) {
      router.navigate(router.fallbackRoute, { trigger: true, replace: true });
    } else {
      logger.error('Router navigation failed, and no previous location or fallbackRoute could be restored.');
    }
  }`

because of previosLocation value is same as current url, my application just sipmly stucks...

my expectation would be, redirection to `fallbackRoute which is configured

How I could deal which this situation?